# Install Android Studio to /opt in Linux (move the 1.9 GB ~/Android/Sdk to /opt)

Tags: linux, android-studio, ide

I downloaded the new IntelliJ IDEA-based Android Studio - [android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux.zip](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/1.0.1/android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux.zip).

I unpacked the zip file to `/opt/android-studio` (it was 425 MB unpacked), and executed `/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh`, which started an Install Wizard that installed 1.9 GB worth of data to `~/Android/Sdk`. After that, running `studio.sh` now starts the Android Studio.

I want to move `~/Android/Sdk` to `/opt/android-sdk`, so it can be shared by all users. Also, the users can't have write access to it, since it's in the root partition.

So is this possible?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux.zip. The linked file only has studio.sh and has clear documentation about installation (stating that you unpack it in the installation directory you want to use) in Install-Linux-tar.txt the contained android-studio-ide-135.1641136-linux.zip.

Comment: While I have not tried having Studio in `/opt`, I run with my Android SDK in `/opt`. You just need to tell Android Studio where your SDK installation is, via File > Other Settings > Default Project Structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's intended to be installed per-user, not for-all-users, the main reason being so that individual users can add/update their SDK components as they see fit -- new versions of things are released pretty regularly. It would be a pain for a user to have to ask an administrator to add a missing API level or grab an update. Also, depending on just how security paranoid you are, you may not be comfortable in general running the Android SDK manager as root.

If that's not an important limitation for you, then you can copy/move the SDK directory to its final home; you don't have to run the installer to place it there. Other than for updates, the SDK doesn't write anything to its installation directory, so it should work once copied there.

Having said all that, the Android tools also have a per-user `.android` directory in the user's home directory. These can't be shared between users, as it contains per-user preferences and AVDs and such. Because of the latter, unfortunately this directory can get quite large.

Comment: Following your advice, I copied `~/Android/Sdk` to `/opt/android-sdk`, and when I executed `studio.sh`, I saw they have an option to specify where to install the SDK, so I selected `/opt/android-sdk`. Android Studio then said it had detected an SDK already exists there, so it would just download updates, and it seemed to complete successfully. It's running well now, thanks!

Answer (score -5):

decompress Android Studio into /opt, then just do

```
sudo chmod 777 /opt/
```

If you're the only person that uses your machine its fine.

Comment: Making /opt/ world-writable? That's a **terrible** idea.